# Beamer: Images slightly shited to the right when using only?

Tags: beamer, only

I am trying to show four pictures after each other on the same slight by using only. The code looks like this:

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \only<1>{
        \includegraphics[height = 6cm]{images/Worldle1.png}
        }
        \only<2>{
        \includegraphics[height = 6cm]{images/Worldle2.png}
        }
        \only<3>{
        \includegraphics[height = 6cm]{images/Worldle3.png}
        }
        \only<4>{
        \includegraphics[height = 6cm]{images/Worldle4.png}
        }

        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:worldle}
    \end{figure}

\end{frame}
```

However, this leads to each graphic being some pixel to the right of the picture before.[image]

Does anybody know what is going on here?

Comment: you are adding lots of spaces, pushing the content further and further to the right: put `%` at the ends of lines